# How to Force domain to with www - htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm using this `htaccess` to force all request with www. but my resources don't loaded:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^shadyab.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.shadyab.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]
```

this is my site:

http://www.shadyab.com/

for example:

http://www.shadyab.com/assets/plugin/slider/css/owl.carousel.min.css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second rule rewrites *everything* to index.html, including all your css

If you really want to rewrite every request to index.html, but still want your resources, you can exclude them using a condition, otherwise remove the rule.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^shadyab.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.shadyab.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|png|jpe?g|gif)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]
```

Comment: my resources doesn't loaded correctly. for example: `fontawesome`